# htaccess rule for slash(/) in place of dash(-)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a htaccess rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^restaurant-([0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-menu$ rest_menu?&id=$1&area=$2&Name=$3
```

The url is as follows: `https://example.com/restaurant-3-place-restname-menu`.

But I want the url to be `https://example.com/restaurant-3-place-restname/menu`.

How do I change my htaccess rule so that it starts working.

**Notice:** the "- " before menu is replaced by "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule i am assuming rest_menu is a php file.

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^restaurant-([\d]+)-([\w-]+)-([\w-]+)/menu$ rest_menu.php?&id=$1&area=$2&Name=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Yes rest_menu is a php file. But it is still not working. once I hit enter it gives the following url in adress bar `https://example.com/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/alive/seo/rest_menu?&id=3&area=testarea&Name=testname`. And the error is "Requested document not found on server."

Comment: Please try the edit! and comment out any other rule which conflicting.

Comment: Okay bro. Will do. Thanx for the help.